# What is the way(s) to represent an embedding of a planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory

As we know there are some ways to state a graph such as: it's drawing, adjacency matrix and sets of vertices and edges. And we know planar graph contains one or more embeddings. My question is what are the ways to represent an embedding of a planar graph?

Of course it is also a question for me that can we call every of these embedding a plane graph?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, an embedding is some sort of function. As [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) explains, one way to do this is to map vertices to points and edges to curves. It also mentions a more sophisticated approach I haven't a clue about. And no, two embeddings would not be considered two graphs.

Comment: How about saying its set of faces?

Comment: Saying what about its set of faces?

Comment: I mean, can we represent an embedding by set of faces? For example each face of a plane graph (embedding) can be detrmined by a permutation of its edges.